# Hive avro table schema not updated after setting properties of table from avro.schema.literal to avro.schema.url

Tags: hadoop, hive, schema, avro

First i have cretaed a avro hive table as below.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE user
STORED AS AVRO
LOCATION '/work/user'
TBLPROPERTIES  ('avro.schema.literal'='{"type":"record","name":"user", "fields": [{ "name":"user_id", "type":["null","int"], "default":null, "columnName":"user_id", "sqlType":"4" }, { "name":"username", "type":["null","string"], "default":null, "columnName":"username", "sqlType":"-1" }], "tableName":"user"}')
```

I was able to see the data.

I have changed some schema, but this time, did by using below code.

```
ALTER TABLE user SET TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.url'='/work/avro/user_schema.avsc')
```

New schema in url is as below.

```
{"type":"record","name":"user", "fields": [{ "name":"user_id", "type":["null","int"], "default":null, "columnName":"user_id", "sqlType":"4" }, { "name":"username", "type":["null","string"], "default":null, "columnName":"username", "sqlType":"-1" }, { "name":"city", "type":"string", "default":"Pune", "columnName":"city" }], "tableName":"user"}
```

Schema is not updated. Table shows only 2 fields i.e user_id and username.

The same thing works when schema is provided in literal as below.

```
ALTER TABLE user SET TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.literal'='{"type":"record","name":"user", "fields": [{ "name":"user_id", "type":["null","int"], "default":null, "columnName":"user_id", "sqlType":"4" }, { "name":"username", "type":["null","string"], "default":null, "columnName":"username", "sqlType":"-1" }, { "name":"city", "type":"string", "default":"Pune", "columnName":"city" }], "tableName":"user"}');
```

But not by specifying url as specified above.

But this is not working. Table schema not getting updated.

Comment: have you found a solution to this?

Comment: Did you find the answer for this? Both literal and url schema are available in hive table.

Comment: Found the answer       ALTER TABLE <db_name>.<table_name> UNSET TBLPROPERTIES('avro.schema.literal'); If you do this then 'avro.schema.url' will be enabaled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The avro schema file needs to be in hdfs and reference could be like below.

```
TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.url'='hdfs:///user/cloudera/categories.avsc')
```